# Converting Lon Lat to UTM Zone 32N in C# with SQLSpatialTools

Tags: c#, sql-server, coordinate-system

I have a set of coordinates; Lon 9.42221521, Lat 56.44978001 and I want to convert them to UTM Zone 32N coordinates. I found the SQLSpatialTools library to do the conversion but I need some help. When I use the following code:

```
SqlChars chars = new SqlChars(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", lon, lat));
        SqlGeography mapPoint = SqlGeography.STPointFromText(chars, 4326);

        SqlProjection proj = new SqlProjection();
        proj = SqlProjection.TranverseMercator(0);  //(or Mercator)
        SqlGeometry geometry = proj.Project(mapPoint);
        geometry.STSrid = 25832;

        SQLSpatialTools.AffineTransform affTrans = new AffineTransform();
        SqlGeometry newPoint = AffineTransform.Scale(6378137, 6378137).Apply(geometry);
```

...the lon lat set gets converted to 578664.03 - 6323756.73

If I check the lon lat set in ArcMAP I get the following values: 526026.284 - 6256221.368

...so obviously I must be doing something wrong. I'm using SQLSpatialTools because it's easier for me to perform some spatial queries later.

Thanks!